# Executing C# in command prompt (cmd)

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd

Python allows the following: once I open cmd I can start python and then run python commands which return results directly in cmd. For example, I type `print word` and cmd returns `word`. Is there a similar thing for C# or the only way to execute C# code is to write it in a file and then compile it?

Comment: If you search for C# REPL (read-eval-print-loop), you will find several possibilities, both on google and here on StackOverflow. The mono REPL seems to be the most mature, maybe together with LINQPad. We're all waiting for Roslyn though :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PowerShell.

This will allow you to access the objects in the .Net Framework as well the objects in the operating system.

Check this simple example:

[image]

Or you can check this advanced example:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx